# Windows Authentication Timeout IIS7

Tags: session, authentication, iis-7, windows-authentication, session-timeout

I am using Windows Authentication to assist in preventing access to a website. This site is not hosted within my network, meaning that the first time I try to access it I have to enter my windows credentials for that server. All this works great.

My problem lies with the timeout. If I use Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication, IIS seems to correctly use the session timeout/form timeout value of 20 minutes.

However, when I am using Windows Authentication it seems to timeout much sooner than 20 minutes. I have not found a way to increase the Windows Authentication timeout value. I need it to be about 20 minutes.

My App Pool settings are set to never recycle the App Pool, so I know it's not timing out due to an App Pool refresh.

This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 website in-case that is a question.

Any ideas on how to increase the timeout of Windows Authentication in IIS7?